# Re: Laravel Notification (Call to a member function notifyNow() on null)

Tags: laravel-5.6

I have this error even if I received data from the request.

> **Call to a member function notifyNow() on null** *{"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0)*:
>   **Call to a member function notifyNow() on null at**
>   *C:\wamp64\www\iaccs-admin-console\app\Http\Controllers\WebhookController.php:31)*

This is my controller:

```
public function handle(Request $request){
    $data = $request;
    \Log::info($data);
    auth()->user()->notify(new WebhookNotification($data));
}
```

What is the proper implementation using notify?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can only retrieve Authenticated user with the following line of code

```
Auth::user();
```

It seems like User is not logged in when that code runs and you get null instead of User Object. First, make sure you have a User object then call notify.

Comment: @Anonymouse703 yeah, your user object was null. please accept the answer so this post will be marked as closed.

Answer (score 0):

@rafay Hassan I already solve it by this query.

```
$admins = User::whereHas('roles', function($q){$q->whereIn('roles.name', ['superadmin']);})->get();
```